# Outlook get FreeBusy information is slow

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop

My code is an MS Outlook addin and is used for creating a absence calendar for 60+ people of a team. The company uses MS Exchange.

I am retrieving their free/busy status with this code:

```
var namespace = ThisAddIn.thisOutlookApp?.GetNamespace( "MAPI" );
var recp = namespace.CreateRecipient( personName );
var freeBusy = recp.FreeBusy( startDate, MinPerChar: 60, CompleteFormat: true );
```

Although this works file, one call to `FreeBusy()` takes about 300 milliseconds. For 60 people and a time span of three months, this means my code takes nearly a minute.

I also tried this alternative:

```
recp.Resolve();
var exu = recp.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser();
var freeBusy = exu.GetFReeBusy(...)
```

but no difference. The same code in VBA shows the same performance.

Is their a trick to speed up this call, or is there an alternative way to get the free/busy information, e.g. by accessing other people's calendar or by talking to the MS Exchange server itself?

Comment: you should create a thread pool to get the info of multiple users in parallel. Thus way you can cut down in the overall time required.

Comment: @Soumen Mukherjee: As far as I know, the Office Interop API does not support multiple threads, therefore a thread calling FreeBusy will wait for the other to return, which will result in the same performance. I thried it out with 3 threads, and it seems to work this way.

Answer (score 1):

Use [GetUserAvailability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/getuseravailability-operation) EWS operation - it allows to request f/b info for **multiple** users in a single call.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly my approach. Thanks for the post anyhow, because I wasn't aware that a single call to this method can return the availability of multiple attendees. This way, I don't need to use multiple threads. As a consequence, I removed the reference to multiple threads from my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found a good solution myself:
I did not use the Outlook Interop API, but calls to the Exchange server itself using the EWS Managed API.

There is an excellent set of [101 sample projects](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/exchange/Exchange-2013-101-Code-3c38582c). (It's really 101 samples!) and a  very good [step-by-step tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/get-started-with-ews-managed-api-client-applications) for getting started with the EWS Managed API.

"Exchange 2013 Get users' status setting programmatically" was the sample that I used.

However, I'm keen to hear about alternative solutions from SO users.